# add a line before each found pattern in bash. using the found pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file that list the attributes found using ldap search like this

```
dsee_simpleauthbinds{cn="1389"} 141962
dsee_simpleauthbinds{cn="1636"} 1029264
dsee_wholesubtreesearchops{cn="1389"} 1638369
dsee_wholesubtreesearchops{cn="snmp"} 35862
```

the attributes are grouped together in 'sessions' eg the `wholesubtreesearchops` attribute is grouped  with all the cn where that attribute is present.

I need to modify the file so that for each attribute,  the attribute is added before the start of the session so the file above becomes this:

```
[dsee_simpleauthbinds]
dsee_simpleauthbinds{cn="1389"} 141962
dsee_simpleauthbinds{cn="1636"} 1029264      
[dsee_wholesubtreesearchops]
dsee_wholesubtreesearchops{cn="1389"} 1638369
dsee_wholesubtreesearchops{cn="snmp"} 358629
```

of course there are far more attributes the idea would be before each new attribute found in the file add the header in the line just before it.

Comment: Where do `ds1` and `ds3c` come from? I cannot find them in the input. Also, why is there a leading `,` before one entry only.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix your example and add your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you with that. See [ask].

Comment: I edited the questions the node are some extra data that are in the real file but are irrelevant to the question if just need to capture the  items before the first curly brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumptions:

- data is already sorted by attribute
- the only requirement is to add a `[<attribute>]` line, ie, the `node="...",` strings in the expected output are typos; otherwise OP needs to update the question with the details on where the `node="...",` strings are coming from

Sample input data:

```
$ cat attrib.dat
dsee_simpleauthbinds{cn="1389"} 141962
dsee_simpleauthbinds{cn="1636"} 1029264
dsee_wholesubtreesearchops{cn="1389"} 1638369
dsee_wholesubtreesearchops{cn="snmp"} 35862
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F'{' '$1 != header {print "[" $1 "]"; header=$1}1' attrib.dat
```

This generates:

```
[dsee_simpleauthbinds]
dsee_simpleauthbinds{cn="1389"} 141962
dsee_simpleauthbinds{cn="1636"} 1029264
[dsee_wholesubtreesearchops]
dsee_wholesubtreesearchops{cn="1389"} 1638369
dsee_wholesubtreesearchops{cn="snmp"} 35862
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'G;/^\(.*\){.*\n\1/!{h;s/{^\(,*\){.*/[\1]/p;g};s/\n.*//;h' file
```

Append the previous line and compare with the current one.

If the keys are not the same, make a copy, fabricate and print a header, then replace the header with the copy.

In all cases, remove the previous line and store a copy of the current line.